# Understanding `TransformedDistribution` behavior on two similar lines of code

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

The two following lines of code does not give the same output. Mathematica manages to calculate the first one but fails to calculate the second one.

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  a^2, {a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}], x]

PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  a*b, {a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   b \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}], x]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are not equivalent. The first is a one-sided distribution (a^2 is nonnegative) whereas the second is two-sided (a*b is both positive and negative).

You can also generate the first from the `HalfNormalDistribution`:

```
Assuming[x > 0,
 PDF[TransformedDistribution[
     a^2, {a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}], x] ==
   PDF[TransformedDistribution[
     a^2, {a \[Distributed] HalfNormalDistribution[Sqrt[Pi/2]]}], x] //
    Simplify]
```

> True